Angular Material <mat-select> Dropdown Not Interactive in Zoneless Angular 18 Until Browser Resize
Body:
I am encountering a peculiar issue with Angular Material's <mat-select> dropdown in my Angular 18.1.0 application. The dropdown does not appear or interact correctly on initial page load. However, once I resize the browser window, the dropdown appears and stays open, but I cannot select any options or close it. After attempting to interact with the dropdown, the entire application hangs, requiring a hard refresh to recover.
Environment

Angular: 18.1.0
Angular Material: 18.1.0
Angular CDK: 18.1.0
ng-bootstrap: 17.0.0
TypeScript: 5.5.3
Stripe.js: 4.1.0

Issue Description
In my component, simple HTML <select> elements work without any issues. The problem only occurs with Angular Material components. Here's what happens:

The Angular Material dropdown does not open or display on initial load.
Resizing the browser window causes the dropdown to appear and stay open.
Once open, I cannot select any options or close the dropdown.
Clicking on the dropdown or trying other interactions causes the entire app to hang.

Code
TypeScript:
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ProductService, StorageService } from 'src/app/core/services';
import { IProduct, IBrand, IProductType, ISizeClassification } from 'src/app/shared/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-product',
  templateUrl: './edit-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-product.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class EditProductComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  productForm!: FormGroup;
  brands = signal<IBrand[]>([]);
  // Initialization and methods...
}

HTML:
<form *ngIf="productForm" [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="product-form">
  <!-- Form content including mat-select and other controls -->
</form>

Specific Example of Problematic Dropdown
One particular issue I am facing is with the dropdown for selecting a brand. The dropdown does not function properly on initial load but appears after resizing the window. Below is the HTML snippet for this dropdown:
<ng-container *ngIf="brands()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Brand</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="productBrandId" (selectionChange)="onTypeSelected($event.value!)"
          placeholder="product brands">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let brand of brands()" [value]="brand.id">
          {{brand.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</ng-container>

This dropdown is part of a larger form that utilizes Angular reactive forms. Despite other parts of the form behaving normally, this mat-select does not open or allow interaction unless the browser window is resized.
Additional Configuration:
I recently removed zone.js and switched to using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. Before these changes, my project worked well. Here’s how my main.ts is configured:
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, { ngZone: 'noop' })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Attempts to Resolve

Ensured that BrowserAnimationsModule is imported once in the AppModule.
Tried manually triggering change detection post data load and interactions.
Updated all related packages to their latest compatible versions.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how to resolve it. Thank you!

Angular Material does not support zoneless without the the provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection() provider function.

To enable the experimental zoneless support, use the provider function provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection :
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection()], // <== this
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

